# How do I keep all contents INSIDE the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an Ebay template. But I have spent 2 whole days (literally) to make everything to stay INSIDE the "frame" div.

But when I resize the page or someone checks it on the phone, all the junk like images and shapes (border items) are all over the place on the white page outside the maroon frame.

I just want everything to be cemented down onto that one div as if it is a canvas and not move nor resize when I resize the browser.

P.S. The cig will not puff due to it being blocked by something. I'm pretty new to this so I'm clueless.

**IMPORTANT***: This website does not display my code properly for some reason. Please copy and paste both html and css sections into https://htmledit.squarefree.com/ to view and see what I see. This site's html viewer is too goofy.

```css
.Frame {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 20px maroon;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  border: solid 1px red;
  color: Red;
  background-color: ;
  height: 60px;
  width: 899;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.cigbutt {
  border: solid 3px white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-left: 510px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  background-color: 7B2424;
  transition: 2.5s;
}

.cigbutt:hover {
  background-color: BF3D12;
}

.cigbutt:active {
  background-color: EE4007;
}

.moretext {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 450px;
  margin-top: -90px;
  width: 160px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
}

.img1 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 640px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class = Frame>

<div class = Header>
Hot Girls And Cigarette Butts
</div>

<br> <br>

<div class = text>
I do not know what to put down so here as an example so here is a hot girl and an interactive circle that looks and acts like a cigarette butt. Please notice how the frame moves but everything else just magically hovers.
</div>

<div class = cigbutt>

</div>

<div class = moretext>
hover over circle to light long press circle to puff
</div>


<img class = img1 src = "https://optimize.webmavens.in/?key=1949128684&url=https://prodimages.everythingneon.com/giant/n105-1565-pole-dance-girls-1-neon-sign.jpg"></img>


<div style = "margin-top: 100px;"></div>

<br>



</div>
```

Comment: Few issues... a) colour hex should start with `#` (eg `background-color: #7B2424`)... b) CSS classes are case-sensitive so `.header` will NOT match `class="Header"`... c) it's not critical, but it's not good practice to have spaces between your attribute name and value (eg `class = Header` should ideally be `class="header"`)

Comment: Sorry to say but there are tons of mistakes in your code. My first advice would be to learn HTML and CSS properly before making this type of basic questions, please don't take this personally, but I think that it's better for you. Byt don't worry I'll provide the solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Primary Mistakes:

1. The attributes such as class must have quotes ("") for their value. So you did `class=Frame` but it should be `class="Frame"`
2. There are some lines in your CSS that did not end properly. Please make sure to have `;` at the end of each line.
3. The background colors are in HEX, so they must start with a hash `#`

### The main reason

1. You are using hard-coded units like `px` for positioning and stylings. Thus it does not scale well, use dynamic units (e.g. `em, %` etc) for these.
2. There are some places where you should have used positioning and flexbox etc instead of margin to create the layout. even your `cigbutt` animation was not working due to using margins like that.
3. There are just too many to actually count and say. so I'll provide the fixed code now

### Fixed code

```css
.Frame {
  background-color: black;
  border: solid 20px maroon;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  isolation: isolate;
}

.Header {
  border: solid 1px red;
  color: Red;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: cursive;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

.cigbutt {
  border: solid 3px white;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #7B2424;
  transition: 2.5s;
}

.cigbutt:hover {
  background-color: #BF3D12;
}

.cigbutt:active {
  background-color: #EE4007;
}

.moretext {
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  width: 160px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 90%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Frame">

  <div class="Header">
    Hot Girls And Cigarette Butts
  </div>

  <br> <br>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
      I do not know what to put down so here as an example so here is a hot girl and an interactive circle that looks and acts like a cigarette butt. Please notice how the frame moves but everything else just magically hovers.
    </div>

    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; gap: 10px;">
      <div class="cigbutt">

      </div>

      <div class="moretext">
        hover over circle to light long press circle to puff
      </div>
    </div>


    <img class="img1" src="https://optimize.webmavens.in/?key=1949128684&url=https://prodimages.everythingneon.com/giant/n105-1565-pole-dance-girls-1-neon-sign.jpg"></img>

  </div>

  <div style="margin-top: 100px;"></div>

  <br>



</div>
```

Comment: wow, thanks! But is there also a way to make the "frame" div not resize and stay in place as the page minimizes/ screen resolution changes?

Comment: Sorry, but did not quite catch your question... can you elaborate more?

Comment: When I view your code in the browser, fully expanded screen, all looks good. But when I manually shrink the screen using the mouse, or look from a phone screen, all contents squish together (button, picture  and the frame readjusts). My goal is to make everything solid. I want everything staying in place where nothing squishes together regardless of the resolution.

Comment: Quite unsure how you want to keep everything at the same position. PC screens are mostly landscape, whilst smartphones are portrait (when not turned). Also mobile screen have another [display ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_high-definition_smartphone_displays) than the most common display ratio's (16:9 / 16:10). Furthermore one of your pictures is 541 x 1000 px. How would you want to display this on a smartphone when everything stays in the "same" position?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @DarkBee . But if you really wanna keep everything intact but smaller then you can use transform: scale(); although I won't recommend it.

Comment: Never mind, thank you so much for your time explaining and fixing my errors! I just figured it out. I just needed to add min-width: 900px; and everything now stays in place when minimized.